# captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: image buffer size is always 360x480 even on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgimage, avcapturesession

I am using the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` delegate method of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. When testing it on the iPad the image buffer size is always 360x480 which seems really strange, I would think it would be the size of the iPad screen.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection { 

    @autoreleasepool {

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
        /*Lock the image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
        /*Get information about the image*/
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);  

        /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

        NSLog(@"image size: h %zu, w %zu", height, width);

        /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        CGRect zoom = CGRectMake(self.touchPoint.y, self.touchPoint.x, 120, 120);
        CGImageRef newImage2 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(newImage, zoom);

        /*We release some components*/
        CGContextRelease(newContext); 
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        UIImage* zoomedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage2 scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        [self.zoomedView.layer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject:(__bridge id)zoomedImage.CGImage waitUntilDone:YES];

        CGImageRelease(newImage);
        CGImageRelease(newImage2);

    }

}//end
```

Is there a reason why the image buffer would be so small, even on iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the [`AVCaptureSession`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is determined by the `sessionPreset` property, which defaults to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`. It doesn't care what the resolution of the screen on the capturing device is; the capture quality is a function of the device's camera.

If you want the capture resolution to more closely match the screen resolution, you'll have to change the `sessionPreset`. Just note that none of the presets correspond directly to any screen resolution, rather they correspond to common video formats, like VGA, 720p, 1080p, etc:

```
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Do you know the max resolution the front facing camera can send to the image Buffer?

Comment: @NicHubbard It'll be different on different devices. Newer cameras can capture at higher resolutions. Not all of those presets are available with all capture sources either. I'm sure there's a list somewhere, but I don't know it...